# SQL in java return wrong data

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a java method like this one below:

```
public String qE (String query, String selector) throws QSLException,    IOException{

//I get my sqlQuery from properties
String sqlQuery = properties.getPRoperty(query);
//sqlQuery = SELECT count(?) FROM employees WHERE ? is not null

PreparedStatement ps = conn.preparedStatement(sqlQuery);
ps.setFetchSize(100);
ps.setString(1,selector);
ps.setString(2,selector);

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

String rs = "";

while(rs.next()){
queryValue = rs.getString(1);
}

return queryValue;
}
```

When I run it with parameters 
    qe(employees, second_name)
then this query should be executed:

```
SELECT count(second_name)
FROM employees
WHERE second_name is not null
```

The problem is that non of employees has second name and I should get 0 and the whole method should return 0 but I always get diffrent number greater than zero.

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't return 0 but always diffrent number like i.e. 2399?

Comment: `second_name is not null` returns everyone with a last name. `second_name is null` returns where everyone has no last name. Also is the last name actually null or is it an empty string like ''?

Comment: Have you tried to execute the statement on the DB directly? If so, did you get the expected output there? If not, we don't have to look at the code but on the statement and the data in your DB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `?` represents a **value** not an object name, so it is equivalent to using

```
SELECT count('second_name')
FROM employees
WHERE 'second_name' is not null
```

Which is **always true** and is **always counted**. In other words, your query counts all rows in table `employees`.

You cannot use parameters to parameterize object names. If you really need to do this dynamically, you will need to construct the query dynamically (by concatenating the name in the query string). Just be sure to guard yourself against SQL injection if you do that (eg by checking the name against a white list or comparing explicitly to the database metadata).

Comment: I figure what's going to be the next question :D

Comment: @JaimeDrq I hope my edit addresses that, and if not, we'll see.